# Package org.codehaus.jackson does not exist

Tags: java, json, jackson

Извините заранее, впервые работаю с JSON.
Проблема следующая:

Есть maven проект, прописала в dependencies jackson и json.simple, вот мой pom файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>PeopleDataJson</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Хотела сделать соответствующие импорты, но получаю следующий результат: Package org.codehaus.jackson does not exist.

Попыталась сделать Resolve Project Problems и получила следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему?

Comment: Название пакета условное, может меняться время от времени.

Comment: Тогда как его импортировать?

Comment: Включите автоспорт.

Answer (score 0):

Это нормальная ситуация с библиотеками. Дело в том, что обратная совместимость не распространяется на библиотеки и фреймворки. Новая версия может не содержать классов и целых пакетов, которые были в старой версии. Посему обновление библиотек бывает довольно сложной задачей, особенно, если возникают проблемы с их совместимостью.
Конкретно в вашем случае есть 2 варианта решения проблемы.

1)можно понизить версию (к примеру, до 1.9.13):
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl
учитывая дату этой версии мне это не кажется хорошим решением.

2. использовать обновленную версию
   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core
   для этого придется менять исходный код.

Решать вам...